# remove first and last character from CODABAR laravel

Tags: php, laravel, barcode

I am using laravel package to generate barcode. it successfully generates the code. but when i scan the barcode. it adds A and B first and the last of the barcode number.

if the number is 12345
it generates **A12345A**

Package I am using is [package link](https://github.com/milon/barcode)

```
<center class="mb-2"> {!! DNS1D::getBarcodeSVG($barcode->barcode, 'CODABAR', .7,25,'black',true) !!}</center>
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The format of **CODEBAR** is [Here](https://docs.aspose.com/barcode/net/codabar-barcodes/).  You will note that as part of the format it adds **A/B/C/D** as start and stop symbols.  They are part of the barcode.

To make the logic clear, here is a simple approach

```php
$x = 'A12345A';
// remove last char
$x = substr ($x,0,-1);
//remove first char
$x = substr ($x, 1);
```

If you want it more compact you can use **preg_replace**

```php
$x = 'A12345B';
$x = preg_replace ('!\D!','',$x);
```

Here **!** is a delimiter.  **\D** matches a non-digit character so it will take care of **A-D** and will not remove anything else.

Answer (score 0):

just briefly reviewed the library and it looks as though you can choose different types of barcodes to generate. For example to generate a EAN8 / EAN13 barcodes using this

```
echo DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML('4445', 'EAN8');
echo DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML('4445', 'EAN13');
```

Unless you actually need the CODABAR format (which has the termination characters A-D) use a different barcode model

Comment: Extra characters also generate if we use EAN8/EAN13